# About Vulcans And Their Feelings

Tags: star-trek

Is there any substance in the brains of Vulcans that makes them feel less feelings?

Comment: Vulcans have just as many feelings as humans, in enterprise they are stated to actually have stronger emotions. Vulcans have practiced means of meditation over thousands of years to suppress emotions, emotional outbreaks, and to act logically. This does not mean that they feel less however. so id say a big No on this as far as ive seen in the shows/movies.

Comment: This years of suppres..certainly created a substance or something for it.. to left it lasting

Comment: Thanx for the edition @Donald.McLean

Comment: I believe it's actually the reverse; they suppress their feelings because otherwise they act viciously and capriciously. See also the Romulans.

Comment: weve seen in enterprise they encounter a sect of vulcans who act on their emotions and their extremely volatile. And just because you surpress your emotions it doesnt create a "substance" that further inhibits, you may create pathways in your brain that bypass certain emotional responces over the years, but your body wouldn't create a "new" substance to something that is actually counter their normal behavior.

Comment: Their cold Vulcan hearts...

Comment: perhaps the character and the real ability to suppress

Comment: While the original question is about genetics, Izkata's answer explains that it has to do with the brain itself.

Comment: its not duplicate

Comment: Yours: "is there something in the brain that makes them less emotional?" Izkata's answer: "their brain can consciously physically modify itself to control emotions". How is that *not* a dupe?

Comment: It's not any sort of chemical or biological process/substance - it's learned behavior & self-control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, Vulcans are quite the opposite. Without their famous discipline they are vicious and highly emotional beings. In TOS we get a taste of it when Spock undergoes *pon-farr*, loses his prized self control and almost kills his best friend.

[image]

The Vulcans have a long history of violence and wars, and it wasn't until Surak came along and taught his people how to control their emotions that they became the apparently emotionless race they are known as. We can still see those warrior tendencies in the Romulan race who are related to the Vulcans, but lack their emotion repressing philosophy.

Comment: like the dude said,it was them character that makes them different

Comment: its like i said XD